# Kotlin's Nullable types in Android Room without Converters?

Tags: android, android-room

I'm following this [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) to understand more about Android Room. The guide uses this example with Nullable Strings.

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") val firstName: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") val lastName: String?
)
```

I tried my own example but replaced the nullable strings with nullable `UInt` and I end up with the error "Cannot figure out how to save this field into database." The error also suggests that I use type converters. But is the issue with nullability or with the unsigned-ness of integers?
More generally is there a guide on what types are allowed in the `@Entity` data classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Room has a finite set of types that it knows how to handle directly when storing and retrieving values. Other types have to either be broken down into these types or converted to such a type.

> More generally is there a guide on what types are allowed in the @Entity data classes?

The Types that can be handled directly are :-

- null,
- Boolean, Short, Int, Long, Byte (SQLite Type INTEGER)
- String, Char (SQLite Type TEXT)
- Double, Float (SQLite Type REAL)
- Byte[] (SQLite Type BLOB)

  - SQLite does have a NUMERIC type but this is more a catchall type.

*As you can see null is a valid type, although Room will not accept null for Primary Key columns (which SQLite does accept) or (I believe) Foreign key columns .*

Hence when you use UInt Room says it doesn't know how to handle the type and that TypeConverters are required in order to convert to/from UInt.

> But is the issue with nullability or with the unsigned-ness of integers? Neither. An SQLite INTEGER can be up to 64bits (signed), so is more than capable of holding any UInt *"The kotlin.UInt is an unsigned 32-bit integer (0 to 2^32 – 1)"* and actually any ULong *"The kotlin.ULong is an unsigned 64-bit integer (0 to 2^64 -1)"*.

The issue is really the limitations of what SQLite is intended for and perhaps the mis-perception that Room is about saving objects when it is about providing an object orientated approach to saving data in an SQLite database.

As an example, consider:-

```
@Entity
data class CoinEntity(

    @PrimaryKey
    val coinId: String,
    val sshort: Short = 0,
    val sbool: Boolean = true,
    val sbyte: Byte = 1,
    val sint: Int = 0,
    val slong: Long = 0,
    val sstring: String? = null,
    val schar: Char = 'a',
    val sfloat: Float = 0.0F,
    val sdouble: Double = 0.0,
    val sbytearray: ByteArray = byteArrayOf(0b0,0x0)
)
```

The Room will generate the following to create the table :-

```
_db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CoinEntity` (`coinId` TEXT NOT NULL, `sshort` INTEGER NOT NULL, `sbool` INTEGER NOT NULL, `sbyte` INTEGER NOT NULL, `sint` INTEGER NOT NULL, `slong` INTEGER NOT NULL, `sstring` TEXT, `schar` INTEGER NOT NULL, `sfloat` REAL NOT NULL, `sdouble` REAL NOT NULL, `sbytearray` BLOB NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`coinId`))");
```

All but the **sstring** column have `NOT NULL` implied i.e. the `?` allows null, so `NOT NULL` is omitted.